# Is there any way to print page number on HTML page with simple CSS in 2023

Tags: php, html, css, google-chrome, printing

I am trying to print the page number on the HTML page, but nothing is working for me. I have already uses these codes

**First code is here...**

```
#content {
    display: table;
}

#pageFooter {
    display: table-footer-group;
}

#pageFooter:after {
    counter-increment: page;
    content: counter(page);
}
```

**Second Code is here...**

```
@page {
  @bottom-left {
    content: counter(page) ' of ' counter(pages);
  }
}
```

I am waiting for your response. :)